# Greedy algorithms criterion/ intution

Tags: algorithms, proof-techniques, greedy-algorithms, heuristics

Can anyone please explain (not just through examples) that why does the greedy approach does not work in this case? Or more generally, is there any particular condition under which only the greedy solution work?
The problem link -https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1832/B. The problem states that we have an array of elements, and we have to perform k operation. An operation is either- Delete the maximum element, or take two of the minimum possible element and delete them. We want the sum at the end of all operations to be as large as possible. What should be the strategy be?
The natural thing which comes to mind, is that do the operation which has the least sum.
However, it is easy to give an counterexample to this, but I want to understand the condition due to which the greedy solution is failing.

Comment: I don't think that there are problems such that *only* a greedy solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is good to delete the maximum element even when its value is larger than the sum of the two minimum elements. Deleting it allows the algorithm to remove the smaller elements in the next iterations.

For example: If the array is as follows: $4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,9$ and $k = 3$.

Then, the greedy algorithm deletes $(4,4)$ in each iteration since the maximum element $9$ is always greater than $4+4$. After $3$ iterations, the sum of the array is $19$.

However, if suppose the algorithm does not choose the greedy approach initially. The algorithm chooses to delete $9$ in the first iteration. Then, it gives the algorithm the opportunity to delete $5$ in the next two iterations. This opportunity is not available in the greedy approach. This non-greedy approach gives the solution with total sum $24$ which is greater than $19$ for the greedy approach.